# Highcharts style Compass chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to make a graph like shown on [this link](https://www.politicalcompass.org/charts/crowdchart)

I already got a chart with `type: scatter`, `min: 0, max: 1` for both axes and tickpoints at 0.5, and i update it dynamically.

How can i make some of the areas darker with a caption?

Here is what i have now: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97rm4qdu/)

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far in either jsfiddle or codepen so that we can help you solve your issue.

Comment: Edited @PriyankPanchal

Comment: I have used your fiddle to create https://jsfiddle.net/xad8puez/ please check if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ps8bnyq3/1/ with heatmap series type. Perhaps it will be better for your needs.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal This looks great. Would you also know how to get the labels from 0.5 to arbitrary text?

Comment: And then add it as an answer so i can verify you

Comment: @ChristianPåbølJacobsen, I am sorry, I need some clarification on "how to get the labels from 0.5 to arbitrary text". Could you please explain?